# WPF DataGrid Binding List of Object that contains Dictionary<string,string> in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to figure out how to display the data from a dictionary property of a list inside a WPF DataGrid GridViewColumn

All the examples I find only appear to map to list of simple entities that can be . traversed like `{Binding Answers.Title}`. Mine however would be more like `{Binding Answers["Title"]}` which doesn't work in XAML

I'm missing something obvious here. Any ideas?

**Edit:** The list contains an entity that contains a Dictionary. Where Answers is the dictionary in the entity.

Comment: Either remove the `"`s or create a proper ViewModel.

Comment: In a Dictionary the path is key or value.

Comment: How can you have a dictionary in an entity

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have a dictionary as the DataContext, and you need to display either its key or value as ListBoxItem. You can try following :

Here Data is the dictionary you can change the DisplayMemberPath="Key", if you need to display key. This can also be used to display data from a property while a complex object is in DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you simply bind the item source to the dictionary.Values as you would any collection and then create a data template as usual for the item

I.e. mygridview.datacontext = mydictionary.values